# Understanding a solution, Let $S$ ,$T$ be unitary transformations in a unitary space $V$ such that $TS=ST$ prove that $S$ and $T$ have a shared basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:V \to V$ be an inner product in a unitary finite dimensional space $V$ and let $W \subset V$ be a sub space such that $T(W) \subseteq  W$
>
> Let $S$ and $T$ be unitary transformations in a unitary space $V$ such that $TS=ST$ prove that $S$ and $T$ have a shared basis

---

In the first part of the question we have to show that if $ T:V \to V$ is a unitary transformation in an inner product finite space $V$ and $W \subseteq W$ is a subspace such that $T(W) \subseteq W$ then we had to prove that the restriction of $T$ to $W$ $T_W: T \to W$ is also a unitary transformation.

this was kinda straightforward because $(T_Wx ,T_W y)_W = (Tx, Ty) =(x,y) =(x,y)_W , \forall x,y \in W$

for the main question this is the textbooks solution:

let $ \lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$ and $V_\lambda$ is the unitary space that belongs to $\lambda$

since $T$ is unitary we conclude that $\lambda \not = 0$

First we prove $S(V_\lambda) \subseteq V_\lambda$ , let $v \in V_\lambda$ then $Tv= \lambda v$ therefore $TSv=STv=S \lambda v = \lambda Sv$ from here $Sv \in V_\lambda$ so $S(V_\lambda) \subseteq V_ \lambda$ (NOT: $S$ is unitary , so it transforms the basis of $V_\lambda$ to the basis $V_\lambda$ so $dimS(V_\lambda) = dimV_\lambda$ and also $S(V_\lambda) = V_\lambda$ )

from the first part we get that the restrict of $S$ to $V_\lambda$ is also unitary  , so there exists a basis of $V_\lambda$ $\{v_1,...,v_t\}$ of eigenvectors for $S$ . since $V_\lambda$ is an eigenspace of the eigenvalue $T$ , $v_i$ are also eigenvectors of $T$.

to sum it : let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k$ be different eigenvalues of $T$ , and $V_1,...,V_k$ are their eigenspaces then $V=V_1 \oplus ... \oplus V_k$.

for all $V_i$ we will build a basis that is made of the eigenvectors shared between $T$ and $S$ in the way we described above and their union will give us the desired space.

can anyone please simplify the solution a bit or try to make it a bit more understandable?

what does the direct sum give us here? and how do the eigenvalues come in place?

Thank you , any help and tips is welcome to help understand! and sorry if there are mistakes in translating hope it is understandable!

Comment: Do you assume that $V$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes it is , will edit and add the info thank you

Comment: For commuting normal operators $T$ and $S$ there exists an orthonormal basis consisting of common eigenvectors of $T$ and $S.$ The proof goes along the lines in your solution. According to my taste it is simple enough.

Comment: What does it mean for a unitary transformation to have a basis?

Comment: @GerryMyerson what do you mean?

Comment: @Adamrk When you say $S$ and $T$ "have a shared basis", you're saying that $S$ and $T$ each have a basis and those bases are the same. However, what does it mean to say that $S$ "has a basis"?

Comment: @Adamrk It is likely that what you're actually trying to say is that $S$ and $T$ have a shared **orthonormal** basis **whose elements are eigenvectors** of both $S$ and $T$. That is, they have a shared "orthonormal eigenbasis".

Comment: @BenGrossmann I am sure that your correction is the correct thing , thank you and sorry for my translations

Comment: @Ben, that's still saying that an operator has a basis (which is a nonsense) when what you mean is that a vector space has a basis (consisting of eigenvectors of the operator).

Comment: @Gerry I don't think it is nonsense to say that an operator "has" an associate basis of eigenvectors. The basis is associated in some way with both the operator and the space that the basis spans, so perhaps both could be said to "have" the eigenbasis.